# LSAT logic game question --> what is this logic?

Tags: logic

I'm currently working on the LSAT's logical reasoning section, and I came across a problem I'm not sure how to solve . 
The logic is:

Here it is:

Selena claims to have psychic powers. So if we find out whether Selena's claim is true, we will thereby determine whether it is possible to have psychic powers.

The conclusion above follows logically if which of the following is assumed:

The answer given is here: If it is possible to have psychic powers, then Selena has them.

How does this make sense? It seems like the problem is saying that if q -> p, then p ->q; which can't hold true, right?

Comment: They aren't asking what you can conclude from what you are given.  They are asking you what you must be given to reach a conclusion.

Comment: It may help to note that the question uses "whether," which gives the desired conclusion the form of a bi-implication.  Should we use "that," we would have to say, "If we find out *that* Selena's claim is true, we will thereby determine *that* it is possible to have psychic powers; and, if we find out *that* Selena's claim is false, we will thereby determine *that* it is not possible to have psychic powers."

Answer (score 0):

If we determine that Selma has psychic powers we determine that psychic powers exist because she has them. But if we determine that Selma doesn't have psychic powers we determine nothing.

But if we assume if powers exist then Selma has them, we can determine if she doesn't have them, then they don't exist.

If p is Selma has powers and q is they exist we have

$p\implies q $

Which isn't enough.

Because nothing implies $\lnot q $ and because $\lnot p $ implies nothing.

If we asume $q\implies p $ we have

$(p\implies q)\land (\lnot p\implies \lnot q)$

Which is enough.

However, I think the question is badly stated.  It asks whether we can determine if psychic powers exist.  Not whether they don't.  And it says if we determined if Selma has them, which can be interpreted as if we determine that she *does* have them; not whether we determine whether or not she has them.

Answer (score -2):

What this means is that if psychic powers are real then that means Selena has them because it is more likely for her to be true because it was just proven.

Comment: What does "her to be true" mean?

Comment: What do you mean, If you read the sentence then it makes sense

Comment: The word "claim" is missing.  "...more likely for her *claim* to be true..."